# StackOverflowException on DownloadString (And Invoke)

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I seem to be getting a StackOverflowException in C# on a WebClient.DownloadString. Im not sure how I did it and its currently making me a bit angry as its been happening for the last three days.

Basically what I made was a web scraper that cycles through a whole lot of pages and extracts data from it, links to be exact. The problem occurs at random when it hits this piece of code:

```
try
{
    derp = web.DownloadString(site + pageincr);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
```

Site being the site to scrape from and pageincr being what page its up to. So it gets the data, processes it, then if pageincr is NOT larger that the maximum page set, it will increase pageincr then start the function again. But at the most random moments it stops on the pice of code above with the error 'StackOverflowException'. What strikes me odd is that it occurs on a DownloadString function and it happens at random. If it were a real StackOverflow would it not stop the code immediately?

If its possible at all to prevent this, please tell me.

**Edit:**
It seems its just stopped it on this code:

```
this.Invoke((Action)delegate
{
    console.SelectionFont = new Font(console.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    appendConsole("\r\n===[ Page: " + pageincr + " ]===");
    console.SelectionFont = new Font(console.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
});
```

for StackOverflowException. This is getting quite strange.

Comment: Do you still get the error if you comment out the line `appendConsole("\r\n===[ Page: " + pageincr + " ]===");`?

Comment: I'll try that now. Its hard to test because it only happens after hundreds of pages

Comment: Can you open the call stack (Debug->Windows->Call Stack) and see which methods are filling it up when the exception is thrown?

Comment: They all tell me line 852 which would be:
    scrapeStart();
Which is what I use to restart the function. I'm not sure doing x(); inside the function x is very stable is it? Are there any alternatives to going back to the start of the function?

Comment: This sort of flow is called [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).  Sometimes you can rewrite the function into a loop, but in this case I would keep track of visited URLs to make sure you aren't following circular links between pages.  If that doesn't work, maybe add a parameter to scrapeStart() to keep track of depth and stop at a certain depth.

Comment: What do you mean by `restart`? Does this mean `scrapeStart` repeatedly calls itself in case of a timeout or some other other problem?

Comment: It calls itself until pageincr is == the maximum page

Comment: In that case it may simply be a matter of putting 'for (int pageincr = (minval); pageincr <= (maxval); ++pageincr)' around the method body and removing the recursive call.

Comment: Now it doesn't seem to move to the next page (go back to the start of the loop). I commented out the scrapeStart(); and added this to the start of the function:

for (int pageincr = (Convert.ToInt32(pgstart.Value)); pageincr <= (Convert.ToInt32(pageno.Value)); ++pageincr){ and closed it off at the end. pgstart being the starting page and pageno being the end page

Comment: Unfortunately it's difficult to debug over the internet.  If the entire function is short enough and you're able to post it, that will help.  Otherwise you'll have to set a breakpoint and step through with the debugger to see where the execution goes.

Comment: Sorry, missed that little semicolon :)  Remove the semicolon and add braces { } around the code which should repeat.

Comment: That was a really great idea, thanks! I found the problem and fixed it and now it seems to be looping perfectly :D